# Shopify Collection Page - add code disappearing?

Tags: shopify

i'm new to Shopify and i'm struggling with the following.

I added a sentence to the product-card-grid.liquid page so it would show under each product, but when the Collection Grid loads in the browser, it shows the sentence i added for a split second, then disappears. It even doesn't show in Chrome Inspect.

What am i doing wrong/missing?

thanks.

Comment: Please delete your duplicate Question.

Answer (score 0):

I now have it showing! i simply added a background-color to the grid-view-item div on the Collection View page and now it shows my sentence. Weird, but works.